# Pandas groupby throwing KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, pandas-groupby

Pandas throws a KeyError for this code even though all columns exist in the dataframe and I have already checked for spaces in the name:

```
violations_zipcode = final_df.groupby([final_df['FACILITY ZIP', 'FACILITY NAME']])['VIOLATION DESCRIPTION'].count().reset_index(name='No. Violations').sort_values(by='No. Violations', ascending=False)
```

Here's what the dataframe looks like:

```
     VIOLATION DESCRIPTION     FACILITY ZIP  FACILITY NAME
0    Poor hygiene              90210         Starbucks
1    Lack of seating           70024         Domino's
2    Insufficient ventilation  34567         Geppetto Pizza
3    Rodents                   00345         Taco Bell
4    .....                    .....         .....
```

What can it be?

Comment: Could you show the data in final_df?

Comment: @PaulBrennan, just updated the question.

Comment: Please paste the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group by syntax is incorrect. It should be

```
final_df.groupby(['FACILITY ZIP', 'FACILITY NAME'])['VIOLATION DESCRIPTION'].count()...
```

Check groupby [syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):